# How do I select specific fields in QueryBuilder with joins

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 2.7.7 with Doctrine 2. I have a query that joins four tables. In my twig file I only need to render three bits of information from the various tables. I want to select just those fields to hopefully optimize the query instead of returning everything.

Here is my current code for the select:

```
$qb = $em
        ->getRepository('BillingBundle:InvoiceLine')
        ->createQueryBuilder('il')
        ->select('a.id, o.organizationName, i.id')
```

I go on to join the other tables, etc. The problem is the i.id is overwriting the a.id so only two elements are returned instead of three.

How do I either alias the selected fields or create an associative array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
>select('a.id AS a_id, o.organizationName, i.id AS i_id')
```

Then you can access them under $obj->a_id and $obj->i_id respectively.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I was trying all different types of array configurations and only getting errors. Documentation seems weak on this.